conceptual diagram abstraction and null values
In the conceptual scheme, which design solution is preferable to adopt if in a class there is an attribute which 1/10 of the cases has a value and for the rest 9/10 it has none? Should we keep the attribute in the class/entity or is it a solution to separate it and then create an association?
I should keep it in the class and then manage it during the restructuring of the scheme.

Conceptually, in UML both designs are equivalent, since a property is either an attribute or an owned association end.  More details here, where you could just replace the * multiplicity with 0..1.
Technically, in the database it is however a little bit different: The association is implemented with a join to another table. There is some overhead for doing the join. And if you're going to get it only when needed, there is a higher overhead. Up to you to see what advantage you'd value the most and what inconvenience you prefer to avoid (and benchmark if it's about performance):

As a benefit of the separate class, you could save a tiny amount of space. But is it really worth it, as most of the DB engine do already save space for null values (at least for strings)?
The benefit of the attribute is time, as it is available without query overhead. You just have to deal with the potential null value.

As a rule of thumb, attribute implementation is most generally the preferred alternative in your case, unless the the attribute describes a distinct object with its own identity (test: would it have sense to add other attributes to the potential separate class).

I ask you for further clarification. if the optional attribute has values ​​only in certain circumstances that depend on another class is it always better to have it as optional in the class? on a conceptual level if I separate it into another class am I not giving implementation information that in a conceptual scheme I shouldn't give?

Also consider creating a subclass. It inherits all attributes of the original class and it adds the extra attribute. Create an instance of the subclass if you need this attribute and create an instance of the original class if you don't need it.

@www.admiraalit.nl this is also a valid alternative. Especially if what you can do with, or the behavior of is different.

@dok it'll be difficult to answer to too general questions.  "that depend on another class" immediately raises the question if this "dependency" is in fact an association with another class, in which case you could wonder if the attribute is really related to the first class, or if it should not be moved into an association class.  My guiding principle would be to see if the attribute corresponds to an object that has its own identity, i.e. the value of the "outsourced" attribute could change and all objects linked object would then adopt the new value.
